# Deleting aMySQL database with a button in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wanted to delete a row in mysql phpmyadmin database through a button in AssetApprovalForm.php, but when I clicked on the decline button in AssetApprovalForm.php nothing happens.

[This is the image for AssetApprovalForm.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YonEA.png)

This is my code in AssetApprovalForm.php

```
<form action='delete.php?SN="<?php echo $SerialNumber; ?>"' method="post">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="inputfield">
            <input type="text" id="decline" name="decline" value="Decline" class="btn" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="inputfield">
            <input type="text" id="submit" name="accept" value="Approve" class="btn">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have included JavaScript in my AssetApprovalForm.php to perform a pop up after the button is clicked.

```
    <script>
      $("#decline").click(function(){
        swal("Bruh!", "This ticket has been declined", "error");
      });
    </script> 
    <script>
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        
        swal("Nice!", "This ticket has been approved", "success");
      });
    </script>
```

This is my code for delete.php

```
    <?php 
    include 'db_connection.php';

    $SerialNumber = $_GET["serial"];
    $query = "DELETE * FROM waiting_approval WHERE SerialNumber = '" . $SerialNumber . "'";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location: AssetApprovalList.php');
        exit;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error declining request";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: It's time to graduate from a UI (phpmyadmin) to a programming language (PHP).

Comment: Be wary of executing 'hard deletes' within your user interface.

Comment: damnnn you saved my life cause i totally forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Current:-

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="inputfield">
      <input type="decline" id="decline" name="decline" value="Decline" class="btn">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="inputfield">
      <input type="text" id="submit" name="accept" value="Approve" class="btn">
   </div>
</div>
```

I think your input type is wrong it should be `type="text"` not `type="decline"`
and for submit button it should be `type="submit"` not `type="text"`

Comment: change your  `<input type="text" id="submit" name="accept" value="Approve" class="btn">` to `<input type="submit" id="submit" name="accept" value="Approve" class="btn">`

correct your input type for submit button

Comment: changed but now it's the accept button that is reacting to my delete function, it will bring me to AssetApprovalList.php but nothing is deleted